# Symfony generation

Tags: symfony1, code-generation, symfony-1.4

When I generate module in symfony 1.4, it creates (for example) 'New' and 'Create' methods like this:

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->form = new SomeForm();
}

public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST));

  $this->form = new SomeForm();
  $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
  if ($form->isValid())
  {
    $res_object = $form->save();
    $this->redirect('results_show', $res_object);
  }

  $this->setTemplate('new');
}
```

With `--non-verbose-templates` it generates something like the code below (I modified it to show only the creation part):

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST));

  $this->form = new SomeForm();
  if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST)) {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $res_object = $form->save();
      $this->redirect('results_show', $res_object);
    }
  }
}
```

What's the reason of such default generation? I think that method below is more compact, adds lesser routes and actions and doesn't change URL for first and next (if there were errors) form displaying. But the default generation method should be the best or the most often usable. So, what do guys from Sensio Labs know, but I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first template is better suited to building a RESTful application with Symfony.

If you want to use the clever [sfObjectRouteCollection](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing#chapter_10_sfobjectroutecollection) class for creating a collection of routes then both the executeNew and executeCreate methods would be expected.

sfObjectRouteCollection by default creates routes for the following actions:

> list, new, create, edit, update, delete, and show.

You are correct that your preferred template has only one URL but really this is not a problem if you are using Doctrine/Propel forms and then the helper **form_tag_for()**.  This helper takes the form and name of the route collection as arguments then figures out for itself which is the the correct route/url to use from the collection.

Comment: But there can be such a situation. User filled form (some_form/new), but made some mistakes (redirected to some_form/create). He had no more time to complete this task, but he wanted to finish some filling in future (or just refill the form). What does the user do in this situation? Yes - bookmarks the page. But what will he see, when he comes back?! 404! Cause he will return to the action that works only with POST method (some_form/create). I don't think it's good.

Comment: new and create can share the same url and the routes can be differentiated by request type

Comment: Of course, but you should add custom rules yourself to make correct setup and this won't work "from the box". Am I right?